# Cambiar color de las filas de un DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Necesito cambiar las filas de un DataGridView que contiene información de los empleados por día, es decir una fila1 dia1, fila2 dia2, fila3 dia3, y así sucesivamente para cada empleado, el color puede ser intermitente, es decir codigo 1 un color1, codigo 2, color 2, codigo 3, color 1

[image: ejemplo de como debe quedar]

Edicion comentario:

```
dgvRecords.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(222, 222, 222); 
dgvRecords.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: dgvRecords.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(222, 222, 222);
dgvRecords.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;

pero solo alterna los colores en las filas

Comment: @Alex, edita tu pregunta y pon el código ahi

Comment: la propiedad misma te dice que hace eso. Deberias recorrer el grid y en fila que encontres tu valor, le das el color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código debes ponerlo en el **evento DataBindingComplete** del **DataGridView**:

```
 var gridView = (DataGridView)sender;
 var codigo = gridView.Rows[0].Cells["Codigo"].Value.ToString();
 Color color = Color.Blue;
 Color colorAux = Color.White;
 Color tmpColor;

 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
 {
    if (row.Cells["Codigo"].Value.ToString() == codigo)
    {
       row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color;
    }
    else
    {
       codigo = row.Cells["Codigo"].Value.ToString();                    
       tmpColor = color;
       color = colorAux;
       colorAux = tmpColor;
       row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color;                    
    }
 }
```

Lo que se hace es primeramente guardar en una variable el código que tiene la primera fila de tu **DataGridView**, posteriormente hacemos un **ciclo foreach** que recorrerá todas las filas del **DataGridView**, y preguntamos si el código de la fila que estamos recorriendo es igual al código que previamente habíamos guardado en la **variable codigo**, de ser igual pues le damos color a la fila. En caso de que el código guardado sea distinto a la fila que estamos recorriendo, pues digamos que hacemos una rotación de los colores que estamos empleando, y la **variable codigo** ahora guardará el código de la fila que estamos recorriendo. Y así se irán coloreando del mismo color hasta que encontremos un código diferente y entonces se volverá a hacer una rotación de colores y así sucesivamente, se irá repitiendo el proceso.

**Importante:**

Para acceder a una celda de una fila(row) del **DataGridView** puedes hacerlo de estas formas:

```
row.Cells["Codigo"].Value //Usando el nombre de la columna, es un string.
row.Cells[1].Value //Usando el índice de la columna, es un entero.
```

Comment: gracias hermano la verdad gracias, funciona tal y como me lo imaginaba!!! :)