# Como cambiar el color de fondo de celdas en un DataGridView correctamente

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, .net-core, datagridview

Estoy cambiando el color de fondo de las celdas de un **DataGridView** según el resultado de un campo booleano en una consulta a **Access**

Lo hago de la siguiente manera, esto lo hago cuando ya he cargado los datos en el DataGridView mediante el **DataSource** llenándolo con un **DataSet**

```
private void CambiarColores()
{            
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn Col in DgvLisCieDet.Columns)
    {
         foreach (DataGridViewRow Fila in DgvLisCieDet.Rows)
         {
              if (Col.Name == "NomCol")
              {
                   bool VBool = Convert.ToBoolean(MyDataSet.Tables["DatosCons"].Rows[Fila.Index][2].ToString());
                   Fila.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = VBool ? Color.LightGreen : Color.LightSkyBlue;
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Eso lo hace, debo decir que no se del todo y no entiendo correctamente los recorridos de los foreach pero ese código me cambia el color

Lo hace bien una vez, pero cierro el formulario y cuando abro de nuevo me salta el siguiente error:
***Excepción System.InvalidOperationException: 'La operación no es válida porque origina una llamada reentrante a la función SetCurrentCellAddressCore.'***

Pero la excepción salta en la parte de datos al consultar y llenar el DataSet por segunda vez

---

[image: Imagen de error]

----------

Que otra forma hay de cambiar el color de fondo de las celdas?
He leído que ejecutan el cambio de color con otros eventos el DataGridView pero no lo se del todo
A que se debe esa excepción desde la parte de datos por segunda vez?

Comment: Revisa estos links: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426296/cambiar-color-de-las-filas-de-un-datagridview-c/426382#426382  y  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429218/cambiar-color-de-fondo-de-la-fila-de-un-datagridview/429334#429334

Comment: En dónde mandas a llamar CambiarColores y a ListarCierresCajaDAL?

Comment: Los llamo desde el evento de un ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted primero consulta después llena y por ultimo cambia color

Answer (score 0):

Una de las opciones para colorear un DataGridView es primero llenarlo de datos y despues darle el formato al DataGridView recorriendo las filas(Rows) de la tabla con un foreach.
Por ejemplo:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in miTabla.Rows)
        {
   /// Condicion que se colorea toda la fila si el valor de la celda 4 de la fila es 0
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Myrow.Cells[4].Value) == 0)
            {
                ///Colorea la letra de la celda
                Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                /// Colorea el fondo de la celda
                Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]